# Create a new variable based on values in two columns and list of values in a vector

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with columns "V1" and "V2".

```
Z<- c('931', '907','905','902','8552','855','8542','854','8532','853','852','851','850')
```

I want to add a new variable "Match" to the dataframe which takes the values `1`, `2`, or `3` if the following conditions satisfies:

`Match=1`, if value in `V1` and `V2` are same

`Match=2`, if value in both `V1` and `V2` contain any of the values in vector `Z`

`Match=3`, if value in `V1` or `V2` contain any values other than the values in vector `Z`

The resulting dataframe should have the values as given in column `Match`.

```
V1      V2      Match
8552    689     3
576     8552    3
8552    907     2
8552    85      3
8552    902     2
8552    783     3
931     367     3
8552    1090    3
8552    905     2
8552    8552    1
8552    1004    3
113     907     3
8552    1001    3
8542    564     3
850     720     3
```

Comment: row 10 matches 1 and 2. Take the lowest value there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a case_when statement from the {dplyr} package. like so:

```
df %>% mutate(Match = case_when(V1 == V2 ~ 1,
                                V1 %in% Z & V2 %in% Z ~ 2,
                                !(V1 %in% Z) | !(V2 %in% Z) ~ 3)
```